# HTML File is not visible in IIS manager sites

Tags: html, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I want my HTML5 game to "host" on a website. I have web server (IIS 8.0).

I'm making something like this: when I write localhost/goblins in my browser I want my html file to be executed and to start playing. However, I can't add my html file to the sites folder in IIS manager for a simple reason. When I click browse my file is not visible. Why is that?

Comment: Can you please share a screen shot of your IIS Manager? It will make it easier to understand what you are doing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/6Q9vmjY

Comment: Solved.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRcQq8U4WbY